# Renault Clio 2007 1.2i ticking sound at one accelerator position

Tags: engine, renault, knock, clio

I have a Renault Clio 1.2i and the engine (I guess) makes a ticking sound only when accelerator is slightly pressed down (usually the location where I'd like to keep my speed and not accelerate), if I press slightly less or press down more, it no longer ticks.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!